# Web based configuration SW - using JSON-RPC

Tags: javascript, json, configuration-management

Looking for an web-based "configuration" software. The idea/hopes how  it should works (with some fictional examples) :

1. The browser send to the server a request for configuration, e.g. sends `GET /config`
2. The server sends to the browser some HTML/CSS + a couple of JavaScript utilities. The page should contain everything for an nice "single-page" (`Angular.js`?) application, plus the JavaScript part should implement `JSON-RPC 2.0`.
3. After the page load, that page should contain 2 main columns,

   1. the sidebar where the configuration categories (menu) will appear, such: "Email-setup", "Colors", "Paths" e.g. any categories, what should be configured with the form values, and
   2. the main column where the given forms will appear
4. The browser ask the server for the "categories" (for the menu) using JSONRPC, e.g. something like: `POST config` with an JSON content such: `{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"getmenu",...}`
5. The server responds with the left menu items as JSON
6. The browser renders the sidebar menu based on the got JSON
7. The user clicks on some "menu item".
8. The browser sends to the server JSONRPC call, to obtain the configuration items for the given category, e.g. "Colors"
9. The server responds with JSON, what should contain:

   - all form definitions
   - the default values
10. The browser renders the form items, e.g. texfiels, checkboxes and so on, based on the obtained JSON response
11. When the user changes some value, the browser javascript should send to the server (again via JSONRPC) the changed value to "verification".
12. When the user press "Save config", the browser should send to the server all configured values (of course - JSONRPC -> "save").

I'm looking for the "browser side" of the above - e.g. the JavaScript part. (Of course, the server part is every-time different it is application dependent - and the JSONRPC/server could be implemented in any language - simply the server should respond with an valid JSON-RPC response.)

Another:

- should be open-source (licence allowing to use it in open-source projects)
- mobile friendly

Some suggestions how to address the configuration needs for *different* applications, without the need design zilion hand-made HTML-forms - e.g with pure JSON-RPC calls?

**EDIT: Just found**

http://schemaform.io - what is really close, to what i want. It:

- defines and validates the form using a JSON schema
- allow create custom form fields (like date picker, or color picker)
- generates nice looking forms

It based on angular.js - nearly OK - the drawbacks are

- is doesn't uses JSON-RPC - e.g. the schemas doesn't "comes" from an well-defined standardized API
- doesn't allows server-side verification when form-values changes

**Also**, similar SW as above  - http://www.angularforms.org

Maybe some "bridge" between JSON-RPC and the above SW would be OK - or something similar. :)